# How can I update Yarn version 1.5.1 when npm uninstall -g yarn and npm uninstall -g yarn doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

How can I update yarn when npm uninstall -g yarn and npm uninstall -g yarn doesn't work
My version is 1.5.1 and I'm using windows 10

```
npm uninstall -g yarn

removed 1 package, and audited 1 package in 18s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

```
npm upgrade --global yarn
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pickAlgorithm')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\qxz3xng\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-02T05_54_25_455Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm uninstall -g yarn`

`npm cache clean --force`

`npm install -g yarn`

if still doesn't work, check the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn` and reinstall it.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Also I don't have Yarn in that directory. What do you mean by reinstall it? How?